# Is it possible set the address outside the code, in config file in xamarin android?

Tags: android, wcf, xamarin

I am trying to do a simple application that it is a WCF service that it will be consume by a WPF application and a xamarin android application.

In the WPF application, the configuration of the client proxy to consume the service is in the app.config file, so i can set there the address of the service.

However, in the android application, all the examples that I see create the binding in code, and the address is set in code. Something like that:

```
namespace ServiceAgent
{
    public class CalculatorServiceAgent
    {
         private static EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.216.1:1234/CalculatorService.svc");
        private static BasicHttpBinding binding;

         static CalculatorServiceAgent()
        {
            binding = CreateBasicHttpBinding();
         }

        private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttpBinding()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            };

            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
             return binding;
        }

         public async static Task<int> DoSum(int value1, int value2)
        {
            ICalculatorService _client;
             try
            {
                _client = new CalculatorServiceClient(binding, endPoint);
                var res = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(_client.BeginDoSum, _client.EndDoSum, value1, value2, null);
                await res;
                 return res.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
             {
                 throw;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

But the problem that I see in this case is that if the address of the service is changed, I have to modify the application and compile again, something that I could avoid if the configuration could be in an external config file.

So my question is, is it possible in android applications to have the configuration outside the code, in the same way than the WPF application?

Thanks.

Comment: even if you have it in an external config file (which is possible) you will still need to rebuild your app every time it changes.  All files that are deployed with the app are included in the signed app bundle and cannot be modified at runtime

Comment: maybe you could consider requesting the configuration from the server